# Array size blows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a snippet of code that creates an array `clusterUniqueMarkers` that stores all the unique objects in the array `clusterMarkers`.

**Problem:** With the help of `console.log(clusterUniqueMarkers.length);` I can see that the size of that array blows up! When the code is executed, the browser CPU & memory usage shoots up and crashes. What could have caused the problem?

**JS Code**

```
// MarkerClusterer click handler
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mc, "clusterclick", function (cluster) {

    // Find number of unique LatLng in clusters
    var clusterMarkers = mc.getMarkers();
    var clusterUniqueMarkers = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < clusterMarkers.length; j++) {

        if(clusterUniqueMarkers.length == 0){
            // Adding first unique marker
            clusterUniqueMarker = new Object();
            clusterUniqueMarker.lat = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lat();
            clusterUniqueMarker.lng = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lng();
            clusterUniqueMarkers.push(clusterUniqueMarker);
        } else {
            // At least 1 unique marker
            var clusterUniqueMarkersLength = clusterUniqueMarkers.length;   // prevent infinite loop when clusterUniqueMarkers.length keeps increasing
            console.log(clusterUniqueMarkers.length);
            console.log(clusterUniqueMarkersLength);
            console.log('j: ' + j);
            for(var k = 0; k < clusterUniqueMarkersLength; k++) {
                // If marker is unique
                if(clusterUniqueMarkers[k].lat != mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lat() && clusterUniqueMarkers[k].lng != mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lat()) {
                    clusterUniqueMarker = new Object();
                    clusterUniqueMarker.lat = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lat();
                    clusterUniqueMarker.lng = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lng();
                    clusterUniqueMarkers.push(clusterUniqueMarker);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    console.log(clusterMarkers);
    console.log(clusterUniqueMarkers);
});
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You're iterating through all the elements in cluserMarkers, and saying: If the unique list is empty, add the current element as a unique one. If the unique list is not empty, iterate through the unique list, and if the current element doesn't match the current unique element, add it as a unique one. What you want to do is say "if the current element doesn't equal **any** of the unique ones, add it as a unique one".

Comment: Also, why are you doing `mc.getMarkers()[j]` when you've already saved `mc.getMarkers()` into `clusterMarkers`? `clusterMarkers[j]` is much more readable, given the rest of the code.

Comment: "if the current element doesn't equal any of the unique ones, add it as a unique one" -> Shouldn't this be done by iterating through all the unique elements and checking if they equal the current element which is what I did? Or I may have got myself really confused. Yes thanks for pointing out the `mc.getMarkers()[j]` issue.

Comment: If you have six elements in your `clusterUniqueMarkers` array, then you're comparing six elements against your current element from `clusterMarkers`. That element isn't unique (and therefore it doesn't need to be added) if it matches **any** of those six, but your current code will add it five times because it's not equal to five of them, and the `if` statement evaluates to true.

Comment: Great I understand what happened now!

Comment: I also noticed that if I added a `break;` after `clusterUniqueMarkers.push(clusterUniqueMarker);`, I dont get the blowing up of the array too.

Comment: You might not get an array that grows excessively large, but the logic will still be wrong. If you just add `break;` you won't end up with an array of unique elements, unless the initial array only has elements that are equal to each other.

Comment: You're right... thanks for your amazing help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You're iterating through all the elements in `clusterMarkers`, and doing this:

If the unique list is empty, add the current element as a unique one.

If the unique list is not empty, iterate through the unique list, and if the current element doesn't match the current unique element, add it as a unique one. What you want to do is say "if the current element doesn't equal **any** of the unique ones, add it as a unique one", which this code will achieve:

```
for(var k = 0; k < clusterUniqueMarkersLength; k++) {
    // If marker is unique
    var unique = true;
    if(clusterUniqueMarkers[k].lat == clusterMarkers[j].position.lat() && clusterUniqueMarkers[k].lng == clusterMarkers[j].position.lat()) {
        // if the element in clusterMarkers is equal to an element already in clusterUniqueMarkers
        // it can't be unique
        unique = false;
    }
}
if(unique) {
    clusterUniqueMarker = new Object();
    clusterUniqueMarker.lat = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lat();
    clusterUniqueMarker.lng = mc.getMarkers()[j].position.lng();
    clusterUniqueMarkers.push(clusterUniqueMarker);
}
```